# How to match CNAME's on Symfony

Tags: symfony, cname

I have this route:

```
api:
    resource: "@WebApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host: api.mydomain.com
```

I want to let users add CNAME their domains to api.mydomain.com and when they use their own domain for example `api.anotherdomain.com` or `anotherdomainwithoutsubdomain.com` i want to show api route.

I tried this:

```
api:
    resource: "@WebApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host: "{domain}" # and also "{subdomain}.{domain}"
```

but it didn't worked. It just goes to main routing instead of `WebApiBundle`.

How can I do this on Symfony? I use Symfony3, By the way.

Comment: By specifying a host in the route config, you are adding a requirement. If you don't want (or can't) add this requirement, just remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so:

> You have to specifiy hosts in order in routing.yml.

So, this is how it works. All specified hosts go for their routings and others will follow last rule. See example:

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

web_main:
    resource: "@MyWebMainBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host: www.my.com

web_api:
    resource: "@MyWebApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    host: api.my.com

web_public_api:
    resource: "@MyWebPublicApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

In this case, `web_public_api` will handle all other domains who pointed to my server. In case user/customer domain.

Later, in controller or middleware, check domain if present in your database. If not present, return `404` or `403` or even `500`.

Comment: That is right decision. One moment: you want to put `www.my.com` and `api.my.com` in parameters, like this: `host: "%site_host%"` for the possibility of developing on local machine.

Comment: @StephanYamilov exactly did this right now as you suggested. Now its better. Now I have a middleware that checks `$request->getHost()` against my database and if fails return http error status code. So no one can use without also add their domain to control panel in my website.